# Autoclose single and double quotes vscode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

My vscode does not automatically close the single and double quotes. I've disabled all extensions, but the problem still persists.

> vscodeVersion 1.15.0 (1.15.0)
>
> MAC osx: Version 10.12.6 (16G29)

Comment: Have you checked your editor.autoClosingBrackets setting? It should be true to enable auto closing quotes.

Comment: Yes, I checked and this "editor.autoClosingBrackets ": true.

Comment: That's weird. What kind of file that you're trying to edit with VSCode?

Comment: I'm trying to edit "HTML" and "JS".

Comment: Which language mode is shown in the status bar the lower right corner of the VS Code window?

Comment: UTF8 | LF | JavaScript | ESLint

Comment: In my case, for "HTML" files, it was showing "HTML(twig)" on the status bar. i just changed to "HTML" thanks @MattBierner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: this is a bug/feature, in that the double quotes auto-close when the cursor has nothing to the right of it.  However, when there is something to the right of the cursor, then your only get one quote.

```
<h1 className="|> <== the closing > on the h1 tag prevents the auto-close.
<h1 className="|" > <== the space to the right allows auto-close to work.
```

I had a similar issue and came across [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26820) that describes it.

Answer (score 20):

Change your keyboard language to US only instead of US International.

Comment: That solved it! But I still like to keep using US-International!

Comment: YES! Unbelievable. This works...but why!?

Answer (score 19):

It's worth noting that vscode has a separate editor setting for auto closing quotes from that of brackets. If you have: `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"` in your settings, then vscode will never close quotes. On the other hand, if you have `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always"`, then it will always add the extra closing quote.